# Rewrite for all URLs

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite something like:

`http//www.example.com/index.php?var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3`

Into

`http://www.example.com/var1/val1/var2/val2/var3/val3/`

I'm looking for a solution to work on an arbitrary number of variables. Can it be done?

Comment: As you accepted my answer, I think you should edit your question and change the URLs. Because my solution rewrites requests of the second form internally to the first form.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this question: [Can mod_rewrite convert any number of parameters with any names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884377/can-modrewrite-convert-any-number-of-parameters-with-any-names)

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884377/can-modrewrite-convert-any-number-of-parameters-with-any-names) can be used in your case too:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
for ($i=0, $n=count($segments); $i<$n; $i+=2) {
    $_GET[rawurldecode($segments[$i])] = ($i+1 < $length) ? rawurldecode($segments[$i+1]) : null;
}
```

And the corresponding rule to that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This rule rewrites any request, that can not be mapped to an existing file or directory, to the `index.php`.

Comment: This does the reverse of what was requested.  It turns "/a/b/c/d" into "/index.php?a=b&c=d".  The question asked about turning "/index.php?a=b&c=d" into "/a/b/c/d".

Comment: Most misunderstand how mod_rewrite works or misstate what they are looking for: “I have URLs like /index.php?foo=bar and want /foo/bar.” But in most cases the are looking for the exact difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The trick is to write a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) that replaces one character (equals sign or ampersand) with a slash, and then use the "next" flag which restarts the rewrite process.

The following might be a good place to start:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php - [chain]
RewriteRule ^(.*)[=&](.*)$ $1/$2 [next]
RewriteRule ^/index.php\? "/"
```

If I got this right, the first rule will do nothing, but only match if the path starts with "/index.php".  The "chain" option means that the second rule won't run unless the first rule matches.  The second rule will try to replace an = or & with a /, and if it succeeds, it will restart the entire rewriting process.  The third rule, which will only be reached after all of the = and & have been replaced, will remove the "/index.php?" at the beginning.