# Renaming PHP URLs with HTACCESS

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am building a web app that puts out a link like the following:

http://www.sample.com/?a=bj7phm

I would like for it to look something like this:

http://www.sample.com/BJ7PHM

Is this possible within the HTACCESS?

-B

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate..

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893218/rewrite-for-all-urls

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128796/pretty-urls-for-search-pages

Comment: Thanks for directing me the right way...will be taking this question down.

-B

Comment: **@Brad Birdsall:** I already answered... Might as well look at my answer and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do URL rewriting, you first need to:

- Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server.
- Make sure you have the proper permissions to add rules to your `.htaccess` file.
  (`AllowOverride` must be set to `All` or include `FileInfo`)

Then create the following `.htaccess` file in your web root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\-_0-9A-Za-z]+)$  index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

You can customize `RewriteRule` as much as you want.

The first parameter is the regular expression to match the `REQUEST_URI` with (relative to the folder the `.htaccess` is in).

The second parameter is what you want to rewrite it to, `$n` being your match groups.

Comment: There need to be a basic guide to mod_rewrites somewhere... Any links?

Comment: **@Chacha102:** Here is the official `mod_rewrite` documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Andrew Moore: Thanks for the quick insightful response. I am trying to get this to work right now and for some reason the code you displayed is not rewriting the URL. Could this have something to do with the link not actually including the text index.php?

Comment: **@Brad Birdsall:** Make sure that in `httpd.conf`, Apache has `mod_rewrite` enabled and that `AllowOverride` is set either to `All` or at least `FileInfo` for your root folder.

Comment: Not to ask a stupid question but how would I verify that? The server has a cPanel interface..would I find that in there?

Comment: **@Brad Birdsall:** Login into *WHM*. Use EasyApache to build Apache with `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in order to troubleshoot URL rewriting rules it helps to turn on RewriteLog (and RewriteLogLevel) - see [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z+]{1,7})$?a=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```