# Using mod_rewrite to substitute variable used in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've gone through a few different questions like:
[Rewrite for all URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893218/rewrite-for-all-urls)

[Can mod_rewrite convert any number of parameters with any names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884377/can-mod-rewrite-convert-any-number-of-parameters-with-any-names)

[Creating dynamic URLs in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845609/creating-dynamic-urls-in-htaccess)

Which helped me change one set of urls from domain.com/script2.php?d=1 to domain.com/(d), but now I'm stuck with something that I can't find an answer for. Currently, I have a set of URLs that are set up as:
domain.com/script.php?a=1

While I know how to change those URLs to domain.com/(a) this doesn't quite help me with this one because variable A is just a numerical identifier, so going from domain.com/script.php?products=1 to domain.com/1 doesn't do me a lot of good.

Instead, it's variable B which is actually the descriptor, ProductName. So what I'm trying to do is have it so that rather than domain.com/(a), I can get domain.com/(b). There is a complication. The reason that the original set up used variable A is that multiple products use the same descriptor in variable B, so I also need to include variable C which differentiates them, so I need the URL to be domain.com/(b)-(c).

Bonus! Remember how I said I had another script that I'd changed from domain.com/script2.php?d=1 to domain.com/(d)? Well, it'd be super awesome if I could set up my this current script to display not as domain.com/(b)-(c) but instead as domain.com/(d)/(b)-(c) because domain/(d) is actually the search page for this other script, so it's a really logical flow and would really simplify browsing, and would let users intuitively move between the search and the products without much work.

I have no idea if this is even possible, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just rewrite everything back to your script file?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Will rewrite everything back to index.php. From there you can parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable in PHP. From there you can decide what page to load based on the given url.

If you have any other folders in the same directory of the rewrite rule above, you can put another .htaccess file inside those that have `RewriteEngine Off` if you don't want them to be rewritten back to index.php. That is what you will need for a css file or site images.

Using this method, you could always do something like this.
domain.com/products/1
or, domain.com/search/blahblah

Comment: The main reason is simple: I'm not much of a programmer, so because I've used htaccess to handle all the other pages on the site, the old "if all you have is a hammer" approach arises. Could you give me some idea of how the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] would be used in this situation?

Comment: Okay here let me try to come up with an example, this is the code I use to determine the given path.
`$path = explode('/', str_replace("?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}", '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`
This gives you an array of the path so, for example,
www.domain.com/search/blahblah/
`$page[1]` would be `"search"` and `$page[2]` would be `"blahblah"`

Comment: And from there you can use if statements to process the page to load, and of course if the path they request isn't one that you process, simply use an else and give them a 404 page :D